# Android studio displaying error: Failed to load JVM

Tags: java, android-studio, jvm-crash

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCpf4.png)

The error message I'm receiving reads:

```
Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\\bin\server\jvm.dll
If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.
```

I am running a 2022 Framework laptop with Windows 11, attempting to install 64-bit Electric Eel Android Studio. I believe this problem originated when I was attempting to uninstall Android Studio after running (breaking) an emulator.

It appears in a small window instead of Android Studio. I already tried uninstalling every Java-related thing, reinstalling Java from the Oracle website, hard resetting my whole computer and deleting all files, and reinstalling Android Studio. Is there any way that I can easily reconfigure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys! I ended up installing Microsoft Visual C++ X64, and then restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact problem happen to me today after the same update.  I went through this thread to find me solution:

[Android Studio Failed to Load JVM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759671/android-studio-failed-to-load-jvm-dll)

Sounds like there are different fixes out out there.  I had to try several before getting it to work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem after installing android studio release electric eel on a fresh windows device. It turns out I was missing JDK.
So what  I did was

1. Installed the JDK
2. Set the jdk's bin location to path
3. Set JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: My other fixes were causing problems, so I wiped my computer clean, freshly installed everything and was getting the same error.  These steps fixed it.  I didn't test it, but I did move the bin location in path up to the top.  I didn't do that before.